# Hitting Probabilities (Markov Chain)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

The transition matrix, $P$, describes a Markov chain for the state space $S=\left \{1,2,3,4 \right\}$:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0.5& 0 & 0.5 &0 \\ 
 0&0.5  &0  &0.5 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The hitting probability, $h_{ij}$ is defined as the probability of ever reaching state $j$, starting from the initial state $i$.

Determine the hitting probabilities for state 4 $(h_{i4})$ for all states $i$ in $S$.

I do know that $h_{44}=1,h_{14}=0$, but I do not know how to determine $h_{34}$ and $h_{24}$. Would be grateful if anyone can help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the specified transition probabilities, we get the equations
\begin{align*}
h_{24}&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}h_{14}+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}h_{34}
\\[4pt]
h_{34}&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}h_{24}+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}h_{44}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which, after replacing $h_{14}$ and $h_{44}$ by $0$ and $1$ respectively, yields a system of two linear equations in two unknowns.